# Concept of weak solutions for ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the inital problem for ODE
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{du}{dt}&=&f(t,u),\\
u(0)&=&u_0.
\end{eqnarray}
If $f$ is locally bounded function i.e., $f(t,u) \leq M_K$ for all $(t,u)$ in some compactset $K,$ then $u(t)=u_0+\int\limits_{0}^t f(s,u(s))ds$ is a locally Lipschitz continuous functions.
Thus, for a.e. $t>0,$ $t\mapsto \int\limits_{0}^t f(s,u(s))ds$ is differentiable and hence by Fundamental theorem of calculus, $u$ satisfies the following weak formulation.
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_0^{\infty} u\phi_t dt=\int\limits_0^{\infty}f(t,u(t))\phi(t)dt +u_0\phi(0) \quad \quad \text{for all } \phi \in C_c^1([0,\infty).
\end{eqnarray}

In conclusion, the above IVP admits a Lipschitz continuous solution (globally for all $t\geq 0$) even for $f$ which can be discontinuous in $t$ as well as $u$ variable!
Is it correct or I am making some mistakes?

Is this solution unique? In other words can this IVP have multiple weak solutions?

Though the concept of weak solution is quite popular for PDEs, I have not seen this being discussed for initial value problems of ODEs in any of the textbooks. Whys is this so?

Comment: In your setting, $\phi(0)=0$

Comment: Nope. Phi which is not zero at origin should  be included to achieve the initial data.

Comment: But if $\phi$ is compactly supported, how can $\phi(0)$ not be zero?

Comment: Yes, it can still have compact support without being zero at the origin. For example support of $\phi$ can be $[0,1]$

Comment: Okay... Then can you define $C_c$ again? I know it as having compact support where the support is contained in the INTERIOR of $[0, \infty)$